# Simple inequality question for infimum of $A = \{n \in\text{integers}:\frac{n}{2|n|+1} \}$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\beta >-\frac{1}{2}$$
There exists $a$ in $A = \{n \in\text{integers}:\frac{n}{2|n|+1} \}$ such that $a < \beta$
$$\beta > \frac{n}{2|n|+1}$$
$$n < \beta (2|n|+1) $$
$$n - 2|n|\beta<\beta $$

I don't know how to solve this, because there is an absolute value.

Comment: If your $\beta$ is negative, you only need to consider negative $n$.

Comment: How do you solve any inequality with absolute values?  Break it into the cases when the expression inside the bracket is less than zero and when it is greater than zero.

Comment: @player3236 That seems reasonable. But what if $\beta$ is more than zero, why don't we have to analyze it there ?

Comment: Surely one can take $n=0$ to eliminate the case when $\beta > 0$.

Comment: @player3236 why would the case be eliminated if n = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ \beta>0 $ take $ n=0$.
If $ \beta =0 $, take $ n=-1$.

If $ -\frac 12<\beta<0 $ then

$$2\beta+1>0$$ and $ n $ should be such that $ n<0$.

So, we look for $ n<0 $ satisfying

$$\frac{n}{1-2n}<\beta $$
or

$$n<\beta-2n\beta$$
$$\iff n(2\beta+1)<\beta$$
$$\iff n<\frac{\beta}{2\beta+1}$$

thus, you can take $$n=\lfloor \frac{\beta}{2\beta+1}\rfloor-2$$

Comment: I don't completely understand how did you get $n = \frac{\beta}{2\beta+1}-2$

Comment: @BiliDebili It is the floor function. to be sure $ n$ is an integer. You can replace $ -2 $ by $ -1$ or $-3$.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid case work you can simply define $c = \beta + \frac 12$ so $c>0$, $\beta=c-\frac 12$.

$$n - 2|n|\beta<\beta \iff n-2|n|c+|n|< c-\frac 12\\
\Leftarrow n<0, - 2|n|c < -\frac 12 < c-\frac 12 \Leftarrow |n| > \frac{1}{4c}
$$

Then if $n\le n_0 = - \lceil \frac{1}{4c} \rceil$ you have $\beta > \frac{n}{2|n|+1}$.